# Black screen in "Tell me why" game, runned by steam

Tags: games, steam

When I try to launch the "Tell me why" game via steam the screens goes black.
It does run and shows me the menu and even the first animation, but the moment the game really starts the screen goes completely black except for a few flashes of colours. When I press escape the screen changes to grey, so I think the game is still working in some way. The audio still works too, the only thing that is not working is the video.
Does anyone had the same problem and found a solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try switching the Proton version the game is using in the Compatibility tab of the game's Properties.

Comment: I already tried that and it worked, because now I can see the scenery of the game, but it have some kind of problem with shadows, because there is a lot more black than it should be. Like for example, if the game is showing the face of a character I can see her hair and eyes, but the rest of her features are in black.